# Pass data to action class using Ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

I need help passing the form data from JSP to Struts2 action class using jQuery ajax. I have given the code below.

What am I doing wrong?

JSP:

```
<form>
Enter email address: <input type="text" id="processPasswordForm" name="password"/>
<input onClick="emailPassword();" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Ajax:

```
function emailPassword() {
    var password = $('#processPasswordForm').val();
    alert(password);
    $.ajax({
        url: "email-password.action",
        method: "POST",
        data: {"passwordEmail": password},
        async: true,
        success: function() {
            alert("Success");
        }
    });
```

My action class:

```
private String passwordEmail = null;

public String getPasswordEmail() {
    return passwordEmail;
}

public void setpasswordEmail(String passwordEmail) {
    this.passwordEmail = passwordEmail;
}

@Action(value="email-password", results={
    @Result(name="success", type="httpheader", params={
        "status", "200"
    })                                                  
})
public String sendPassword() throws Exception {
    if (this.passwordEmail != null) {
        EmailUtility.sendPasswordEmail(passwordEmail); 
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Error:

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: emailPassword is not defined in the browser console.
```

Comment: What kind of error you are getting for above code?

Comment: Use S2 tags for url construction. `setpasswordEmail` -> `setPasswordEmail`.

Comment: @vijayP Uncaught ReferenceError: emailPassword is not defined in the browser console.

Comment: @AleksandrM I have made the changes but same error.

Comment: So you have a JS error? Can't help with that without additional context.